# Collapse Tab In React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm using this package [react-native-collapsible](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-collapsible)
and I wanted to behave the closing and opening of tabs like gmail.
Like when I try to open an email, when it has many threads of replies, when you click the first one, it closes the other thread. When you click its thread, it opens it and closes the other thread. I think this is just a simple react/JS issue.

```
import Collapsible from "react-native-collapsible";

const [collapsedIndex, setCollapsedIndex] = useState([]);

const renderEmailBody = (emailItem) => {
  return (
    <View>
      {emailItem?.body ? (
        <RenderHtml
          contentWidth={width}
          source={{
            html: emailItem?.body,
          }}
          renderersProps={{
            a: {
              onPress: (event, href) => {
                navigate("WebView", href);
              },
            },
          }}
        />
      ) : null}
    </View>
  );
};

const renderEmailData = ({ item, index }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <TouchableOpacity
        activeOpacity={1}
        onPress={() => setCollapsedIndex(index)}
      >
        <Collapsible collapsed={collapsedIndex !== index}>
          {renderEmailBody(item)}
          {item?.attachments
            ? item?.attachments?.map((innerItem, rowIndex) => {
                return <View key={rowIndex?.toString()}>...</View>;
              })
            : null}
        </Collapsible>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </>
  );
};

const renderEmailDetailsList = () => {
  var data = emailDetailsList;

  return (
    <FlatList
      nestedScrollEnabled
      ref={flatListRef}
      refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
      }
      data={data}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View />}
      renderItem={renderEmailData}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: what the problem with current code?

Comment: Hello Joseph. could you be a bit more specific about what is currently happening vs what you would like to have happen?

Comment: @FujiRoyale. Right now, when I click a thread, its not closing it. It does close that thread when you click another thread. Probably issue with this code `onPress={() => setCollapsedIndex(index)}` or `<Collapsible collapsed={collapsedIndex !== index}>`

Comment: @TimoDevs. Pls see my comment above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think initial value should be `const [collapsedIndex, setCollapsedIndex] = useState(null);` not a empty array, also the onpress should be

```
onPress={() => {
 if (index === collapsedIndex) {
    setCollapsedIndex(null)
 } else {
   setCollapsedIndex(index)
 }
}}
```